# Panels in .NET WinForm

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

What do I have to do to see the panel with the things inside which is under the second panel in Visual Studio?

I want to change something in panel1 but i cant see any labels and buttons because panel2 cover it. I dont want to change position of panel2 so what i should do?

[that border is button1 border. How to see that button which is covered by panel2?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yO5Hw.png)

Changing panel2 Visibile doesnt work.
Panel1 is good option to make pages? Maybe groupbox?

Comment: Right click > Send to back. If you're looking for pages, consider using a TabControl instead.

Comment: Document Outline pane (View Menu>>Other windows) is helpful. Drag items up and down to change z-order even if you cannot see them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know from the TabControl to see it's content that you have to click on the tab header in the designer, like you would do on the running program.
Maybe that helps.